# wget wont download actual files

Tags: unix, download, wget

I've looked around for quite a while now and haven't figured out how to sort this out.

I'm trying to download files from a website, but only ever get an 'index.html' returned. This is useless to me, as I need the actual files.
I've been using commands like

```
wget --no-check-certificate -nc -nH -r -k -p -np  --cut-dirs=3 \https://websitename/directory/folder_of_interest/
```

(I have my username and password set up in the `.wgetrc` file).
The above code will return the recursive directories and in the final one will just be the index.html file.

I could really use a hand here.

Comment: why the backslash? (`\https...`) also, does the actual index.html contain any links that don't point to other domains or parent directories?

Comment: @JoakimGebart
I got this syntax off a website (I can't remember where), and it had the backslash so I just went with it. It worked fine on a different site, and the only difference I can see is that the website it worked on had blah.edu:1111/dirs where the ":1111" was a colon and 4 numbers (not 1111 though). I don't know what the "colon numbers" means, but I don't know what it would be for the site I'm looking at, and the random numbers I've tried don't work.

The index.html doesn't contain any links. It mentions a couple of
input type = hidden name=[something]
and also 'pubcookie' a few times

Comment: The wget -r command works by looking for links and images in the HTML code of the URL specified, so if index.html doesn't contain any links or images or other file references then it will not download anything except the index.html file. The colon numbers are TCP port numbers. You only need to specify it if it is not the default (default is :80 for http). [This manual page of wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html#Recursive-Download) is useful too.

Comment: This is the index.html file. The site I type is the second one, but it must redirect to the first site:
<body onLoad="document.relay.submit()">
<form method=post action="https://host?website" name=relay>
<input type=hidden name=pubcookie_g_req value="LOTS OF CHARACTERS">
<input type=hidden name=post_stuff value="">
<input type=hidden name=relay_url value="https://actualWebsite.edu/PubCookie.reply">
<noscript>
<p align=center>You do not have Javascript turned on,   please click the button to continue.
<p align=center>
<input type=submit name=go value=Continue>
</noscript>
</form>
</html>

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? What is it that you want to download?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you have

```
wget \https://websitename/directory/folder_of_interest
```

This originally might have been

```
wget \
  https://websitename/directory/folder_of_interest
```

which is correct because the backslash is escaping the newline, but with your example is it incorrectly escaping the `h`. Remove the backslash or move the URL to the next line.